# How can I access with JavaScript to cache object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I can access the cache via `jQuery.Cache` method.

[image]

But I want to access it in pure JavaScript.

I dont want to use the jQuery command $.cache

I need the translation the pure JS command

How can I do it ?

Comment: `$.cache[1]` for the first element?

Comment: without jQuery. I want to use pure JS.

Comment: I can't understand what you want... `$.cache` is jQuery's cache for storing data that relates to particular elements. It isn't the browser's cache. It only makes sense to access it through jQuery.

Comment: Pure JS command for what? The object you're looking at is a jquery object. It's built as a result of jquery code that runs. It isn't the browser cache. What you're saying is essentially: I see that code snippet created a function to do X, what is the pure js command to do the same thing. There isn't one. If there was, jquery would use it as well.

Comment: @lonesomeday so what youre saying its just a inside structure in jquery for keeping objects , and it DOESNT appear in browser ?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve with `$.cache`. What information do you want?

Comment: @lonesomeday , I want to understand eventually the difference between $.data and $.cache

Comment: `$.cache` is a bunch of information. `$.data` is a function for accessing that information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$` is just an object that takes advantage of the fact the the dollar sign is legal in a JS identifier.

Hence `$.cache` is a property of that `$` object, itself being another object.

So, you can access `$.cache[n]` from plain Javasript, because that's exactly what it is!

Comment: i think its just an inside structure in the jQuery. nothing more. - I thought It doesnt belong only to jQuery but the js  + browser